# Laravel returning null token but user is being added

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I use postman to add user in my Laravel project. I get null token but the user is added, why?

> {
> "token": null }

How I can fix this error? I use Laravel 5.6 and this is my user model:

```
    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use Notifiable;

        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $fillable = [
            'name', 'email', 'password','username','lastname','tel','tel',
        ];

        /**
         * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $hidden = [
            'password', 'remember_token',
        ];

        public function getJWTIdentifier()
        {
            return $this->getKey();
        }

        /**
         * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
         *
  * @return array
         */
        public function getJWTCustomClaims()
        {
            return [];
        }
    }
```

and this is my register controller:

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\User;
    use JWTFactory;
    use JWTAuth;
    use Validator;
    use Response;
    
    class APIRegisterController extends Controller
    {
        //
        public function register( Request $request){
            $validator = Validator::make($request -> all(),[
             'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
             'username' =>'required',
             'tel' => 'required',
             'name' => 'required',
             'lastname' => 'required',
             'adress' => 'required',
             'password'=> 'required'
            ]);
    
            if ($validator -> fails()) {
                # code...
                return response()->json($validator->errors());
    
            }
    
            User::create([
                'name' => $request->get('name'),
                'email' => $request->get('email'),
                'tel' => $request->get('tel'),
                'username' => $request->get('username'),
                'lastname' => $request->get('lastname'),
                'adress' => $request->get('adress'),
                'password'=> bcrypt($request->get('password'))
            ]);
            $user = User::first();
            $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
    
            return Response::json( compact('token'));
    
    
        }
    }
```

I already get an error and this is my question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593883/fatalthrowableerrorargument-1-passed-fromuser-laravel-5-6) and I fix it.

Comment: You have 'tel' twice in your $fillable array

protected $fillable = [
            'name', 'email', 'password','username','lastname','tel','tel',
        ];

Comment: which token are you trying to get? '_token' or 'remember_token'? 'remember_token' is only generated when a user has logged in and then logged out for the first time

Comment: Token , when I add a user

Comment: the CSRF token or the 'remember_token'? - as previously mentioned the 'remember_token' will be null until a user logs out for the first time, then this is generated

Comment: what is your database saying?

Comment: No i mean token not remember token ; "$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);"

Comment: sorry i see what you mean now - try ---   $token = $this->JWTAuth->fromUser($user);

Comment: Field not found in my controller , he dosen't found JWTAuth

Answer (score 1):

I already had a similar problem before, but I realize my`$user->password` holds the encrypted password, not the plain text required for `login()`. Change your code to call

```
$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
```

with `$user` holding the plain text password comming from `$request`.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem adding if condition on register function after create user

```
if ($this->loginAfterSignUp) {
    $token = $this->login($request);
}
return $this->respondWithToken($token);
```

Answer (score -1):

[laravel jwt auth token not recive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM7Es.png)

$token = Auth::login($user);

$token = null;

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).